Preventing zero byte files in SFTP upload caused by 409 Conflict
I am performing an upload of files to Akamai Netstorage over SFTP in an automated workflow. I have seen instances of the SFTP upload running in parallel (difficult to reliably prevent this unfortunately) and failing because they are trying to write to the same file on the server at the same time. The server returns a 409 status code to one of the running uploads and the file being written to is left as a zero byte file at the end of both upload jobs.
When I try re-running the SFTP job, it does not overwrite the zero byte file with the correct content, it sees that there is a file and skips it.
I am using lftp (happy to switch to any other SFTP client) and would like to handle this scenario so that one of the parallel uploads succeeds and the resulting file is not zero bytes.
The lftp command has a LOT of optional arguments that may or may not help. They are not very well documented. I would appreciate some guidance on this from anyone who has encountered such a scenario before and found a good solution.

Why are there multiple upload jobs accessing the same resources? That seems to be the real issue that needs to be fixed, however if you can't prevent this, I suppose a workaround would be to limit the maximum number of FTP connections server-side to 1 (as long as you have that kind of control on the FTP instance). Parallel jobs will either get stuck and start once there's a slot available or timeout and fail. Obviously that will slow things down noticeably, so it may or may not make sense depending on your use case.

Post some logs. There are no codes like 409 in SFTP. That looks like an FTP code. Is it FTP or SFTP (or FTPS)? Why did you tag your question both [tag:ftp] and [tag:sftp]? + It's not clear from your description if this is client or server behaviour. It logs might help explain that.

Thanks for your comments. The help is appreciated. It is definitely SFTP. This is how akamai has implemented it. They support various protocols and I guess they used HTTP status codes across all for the sake of consistency.

I have solved the problem by adding the --continue argument to the lftp command. The continue option is intended to allow lftp to continue previously interrupted uploads. This also appears to change the behaviour from POST to PUT, allowing both SFTP uploads to write to the same file simultaneously without causing a 409 response.
